# Bernoulli's theorem: $\frac{p}{\rho}+\frac{1}{2}u^2+\phi$ is constant along a streamline

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am trying to understand **the Bernoulli's theorem:**

- **$\frac{p}{\rho}+\frac{1}{2}u^2+\phi$ is a constant along a streamline**

I got that:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ + ($\nabla \times u)\times u$ = $-\nabla(\frac{p}{\rho}+\frac{1}{2}u^2+\phi)$

For a steady flow: $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ = 0 and then:

($\nabla \times u)\times u$ = -$\nabla H$ with the scalar: $H$ = $\frac{p}{\rho}+\frac{1}{2}u^2+\phi$

**now, I didn't understand the next steps:**

Taking the “dot product” of ($\nabla \times u)\times u$ = -$\nabla H$ the left hand side vanishes, as ($\nabla \times u)\times u$  is perpendicular to  $u$ and we get:

$(u \cdot \nabla)H = 0$

This implies that $H$ is constant along a streamline

**Can someone explain me this thing in other words please?**

Comment: In a situation like this it is useful to explain the context and define terms as not every presentation makes the same underling assumptions or uses the same symbols. In this case you appear to be working the conservative field case, but using  different symbol for the potential than, say, the [wikipedia presentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle#Incompressible_flow_equation). All that said, this is just a conservation of energy argument; you just have to correctly identify all the contributions to the energy in your case.

Comment: @dmckee, in (2.13) you can find the definitions. thank you!

Comment: Alon, (2.13) of what? There is no (2.13) in you post nor any links to other resources.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to paste the link: http://www3.kis.uni-freiburg.de/~peter/teach/hydro/hydro02.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbf u(t, \mathbf x)$ represent the velocity vector field of the fluid.  Let $\mathbf x(t)$ denote the position of a particle moving with the fluid, then the velocity $\dot{\mathbf x}(t)$ of the particle at a time $t$ will be equal to the velocity of the fluid flow at the point $(t, \mathbf x(t))$, namely
$$
  \mathbf u(t, \mathbf x(t)) = \dot{\mathbf x}(t)
$$
Now suppose that $\mathbf u(t, \mathbf x)\cdot\nabla H(t, \mathbf x) = 0$.  He want to show that this implies that $H$ is constant along the path of a particle moving with he fluid.  Notice that for *any* path $\mathbf x(t)$ we have
$$
  \frac{d}{dt}H(t, \mathbf x(t)) = \frac{\partial H}{\partial t}(t, \mathbf x(t))+\dot{\mathbf x}(t)\cdot\nabla H(t, \mathbf x(t))
$$
Assuming then that $\partial_t H = 0$, and assuming that the path $\mathbf x(t)$ is that of a particle moving with he fluid, the equations written above imply
$$
  \frac{d}{dt}H(t, \mathbf x(t)) = \mathbf u(t, \mathbf x(t))\cdot\nabla H(t, \mathbf x(t)) = 0
$$
so the quantity $H$ is constant along a flow line, as desired!